# Ant task with custom nested types

Tags: java, ant

I'm following the Apache Ant documentation for "[Writing Your Own Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html#nestedtype)" but I can't get it to work with an interface different than `Condition`:

In *CustomTask.java*:

```java
public final class CustomTask extends Task {
    public void add(final Type type) {
        log("Got: " + type + " with value: " + type.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        log("Executing custom task...");
    }
}
```

In *Type.java*:

```java
public interface Type {
    String getValue();

    void setValue(final String value);
}
```

In *DefaultType.java*:

```java
public class DefaultType implements Type {
    private String value;

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And in the *build.xml* where I want to use them:

```xml
<taskdef name="custom-task" classname="CustomTask" classpathref="run_classpath" />
<typedef name="default-type" classname="DefaultType" classpathref="run_classpath" />

<target name="custom">
    <custom-task>
        <default-type value="Hello world!" />
    </custom-task>
</target>
```

But I get the following error:

```
.../build.xml:37: custom-task doesn't support the nested "default-type" element.
```

The crazy thing here is, if I make `DefaultType` implement the `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Condition` interface (as in the example from the documentation) and add to the `CustomTask` class the following method:

```java
public void add(final Condition condition) {
    log("Got: " + condition);
}
```

It works: (!?!?!)

```
custom:
[custom-task] Got: DefaultType@5a39699c
[custom-task] Executing custom task...
```

I don't understand, what is special about the `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Condition` interface that it only works with it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As an aside, what's your reason for using Ant?

Comment: @chrylis That's what is used at the office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue goes away if you add the `loaderref` property to both definitions with the same value (it seems it can be anything, [this is not clear in the documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/typedef.html)):

```xml
<taskdef
    name="custom-task"
    classname="CustomTask"
    classpathref="run_classpath"
    loaderref="my_loader" />

<typedef
    name="default-type"
    classname="DefaultType"
    classpathref="run_classpath"
    loaderref="my_loader" />
```